# Persisting state on browser reload not working in react

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

I have checked on blogs and other stack overflow questions for this. The answer is quite simple and clear, but doesn't seem to work for me. I am using functional component, I tried to use both `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` for a simple counting app. The app still works but the `count` state defaults back to 0 on browser reload instead of the current state in the `sessionStorage`. I must be missing something or I get this completely wrong...

Here is my code...
Manipulating the `count` into and from the `sessionStorage`

```
// Setting the count to the stored value in localStorage...
  useEffect(() => {
    setCount(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('count')))
  }, [])

  // setting the local storage every time count changes...
  useEffect(() => {
    sessionStorage.setItem('count', count)
  }, [count])
```

Handling click events...

```
// The handlers...
  const plusHandler = () => {
    const newCount = count
    setCount(newCount + 1)
  }

  const minusHandler = () => {
    const newCount = count
    setCount(newCount - 1)
  }
```

Printing the `count` using `<p>{count}</p>`

See the  [Full CodeSandbox Project Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-water-yhwvw5?file=/src/App.js:675-689)

Even a short description of what I might be doing wrong will be appreciated...

Comment: I don't believe your sandbox example is working. Perhaps need to hit save?

Comment: I used my incognito tab and it says that **Failed to read the 'sessionStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.**  I have no idea why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `sessionStorage.getItem()` outside of `useEffect` to get the initial state of your counter synchronously:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem("count") || 0, 10))
```